# Angular simple pattern validation question

Tags: angular, validation

I have a very simple Angular pattern like this:

```
<div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="testField" name="testField" #testFieldN="ngModel" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />
    <div *ngIf="testFieldN.invalid"
         class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="testFieldN.errors?.pattern">
        Title is invalid.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="testFieldN.errors?.required">
        Title is required.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I expect that testField should have at least one alphabetical character. This means value like "One11" should be accepted. However, if I enter that value, the pattern error kicked off and shows "Title is invalid."

Can someone point out what is wrong? Also, I expect when the filed is empty, the pattern error should be kicked off, but it is not. Why is that?

To make it clear, this is how I test my pattern and it matches "One11": [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xvLzlH/1)

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern allows **only** alphabetical characters, and not numbers, for example. If you want something that accepts numbers, try:

```
[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]{1,}[0-9]*
```

It's basically:

1. 0 or more numbers
2. at least 1 character of A-z
3. 0 or more numbers

Comment: I believe we use javascript regular expression syntax for Angular, right? So if I only want alphabetical characters, the pattern should be "^[a-zA-Z]+$". Am I wrong?

Comment: Your pattern doesn't allow numbers at all.

Comment: Alexey, so what is the pattern that allows at least one alphabetical character?

Comment: Alexey, thanks but I don't think it's what I wanted. Can you suggest an expression that accepts a string with at least one alphabetical character? And is it a javascript regular expression?